# How to remove Massacdusettes from dictionary in Chrome for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, osx-yosemite, spell-check

I notice a misspelled word being offered for Massachusetts typo as: `Massacdusettes` on Mac OS X Yosemite in Chrome Version 44.0.2403.107 (64-bit).  I looked in `Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary` but there is no entry for `Massacdusettes` to remove, so it appears I didn't add it and it is in the master dictionary.  How can I remove this misspelled word so it is not offered for misspellings like `Massachusettes`?